# OctoPi failed to run camera app

Tags: camera, printing

Device: Raspberry Pi 3A+
Peripheral: Raspberry Pi camera v1.3 (probably third party), connected via CSI port
OS: OctoPi 5.10.63

Im trying to make a test picture with my camera. I enabled the CSI port in the advanced settings and the Pi 3A is up to date. The camera has a red LED shining, so i do believe it is correctly plugged in.

When i enter the command `raspistill -v -o test.jpg` there is the following output:

```
"raspistill" Camera App (commit bab9bf8790cd Tainted)

Camera Name ov5647
Width 2592, Height 1944, filename test.jpeg
Using camera 0, sensor mode 0

GPS output Disabled

Quality 85, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Time delay 5000, Timelapse 0
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

Does anyone see the error?

Comment: Probably OctoPi / Octoprint already uses the camera (that could explain the red LED). There can only be one program accessing the camera; resulting in an error when you try to run raspistill manually. I' pretty sure you can create images from within Octoprint.

Comment: Does OctoPi use the camera automatically? I didnt tell it to do so yet

Comment: I suggest you ask at https://community.octoprint.org/